# Proving an identity for $\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\frac{\gcd(m,n)^r}{m^sn^t}$.

Tags: number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, transcendental-numbers

My task is to prove the well-known identity

[image]

Here all variables are positive integers

I only know  I should use  mobius inversion formula,  but how to proceed I am getting confusion, please any one can help me in this, and is there any article which shows the applications of mobius inversion formula.

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{m,n} \frac{(m,n)^r}{m^s n^t} &= \sum_{d=1}^\infty \sum_{(m,n) = d} \frac{(m,n)^r}{m^s n^t} \\
&=\sum_{d=1}^\infty \sum_{(m,n) = 1} \frac{d^r}{(dm)^s (dn)^t} \\
&=\zeta(s+t-r) \sum_{(m,n) = 1} \frac{1}{m^s n^t} 
\end{aligned}$$
Let $$A_d = \sum_{(m,n) = d} \frac{1}{m^s n^t} $$
Note that $$\sum_{r|d} A_d = \frac{1}{r^{s+t}}\zeta(s)\zeta(t)$$
Therefore,
$$A_1 = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r) \sum_{r|d} A_d = \zeta(s)\zeta(t) \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(r)}{r^{s+t}} = \frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(t)}{\zeta(s+t)}$$
completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation

Comment: if we want to study further on this topic, what are the reference books or what are the resources? thanks in advance.

Comment: @nimmy   What do you mean by "this topic"? It seems this problem as itself does not reflect any branch of mathematics.

Comment: I mean how this identity comes if want to study further,  what r the books

Comment: I think any book mentioning Dirichlet series suffices, for example, *Introduction to analytic number theory* by T.M. Apostol.